# Как работать с двумя state в одной функции aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Я пишу бота на aiogram, ошибка происходит со state, никак не могу понять

```
@dp.message_handler(Command("items"))
async def get_com(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await Process_of_selling.number_of_fruit.set()
    await state.set_state("pages")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        current_page = 1
        data['page'] = int(current_page)
        await message.answer(text="Hi, click what you would like to order", reply_markup=f_keys(data['page']))


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('f_'), state="pages")
async def select_fruit(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    fruit_name = call.data.split('_')[1]
    await call.answer(text=f"You chose {fruit_name}", show_alert=True)
    await state.finish()
    #ошибка происходит из-за нижней части
    await state.set_state("number_of_kg")
    async with state.proxy() as data: #хочу открывать словарь со state = 'number_of_kg'
        data['fruit'] = fruit_name
        data['kg'] = 0
        print(await state.get_state())
        await call.message.edit_text(text=f"Вы хотите заказать {data['fruit']}? Тогда выберите килограмы", reply_markup=menu(kg=data['kg']))
```

ошибка:

```
TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardButton is not JSON serializable
```

Можете пожалуйста подробно объяснить, где именно не так, я сам не спец, даже начинающий можно сказать